# android arrayadapter declaration Error

Tags: java, android, arrays, adapter, android-arrayadapter

When i declare the array adapter up as golbal public the app crash when i just start it

but when i declare it inside the onClick method it works fine

i need to know that happen ?

```
package com.rafahya.myapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,arrayList);
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList.add("momen");
        arrayList.add("ahmed");
        arrayList.add("Amin");
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder momen = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Enter the Zip Code")
                        .setAdapter(arrayAdapter , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Momen" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                momen.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,arrayList);
```

With this line you are trying to access MainActivity before it is initialised. When you type this in the `onClick` it will be executed when you are inside `onCreate` and the class is already initialised.

As to how to fix it- First declare the variable

```
public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
```

and then inside the `onCreate`

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,arrayList);
```